# Multiplayer game sdk for ios and android

Tags: android, game-design, ios, multiplayer

I am working on a multiplayer game supporting Android and IOS.

For IOS Game-Center seems promising. But its IOS only.

OpenFeint could be a option, but now GREE has stopped supporting it.

Is there any other multi-platform SDK which I can use for both IOS and Android?

---------EDIT------

I could not find any good service which provides their own server and SDK for both IOS and android. So finally I chose to go with my own server on AWS-EC2 + python tornado + Websocket. If anyone want to know more plz contact...

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean a multiplayer SDK that works across platforms (i.e., Android users can play with iOS users), or just one that will work on each platform?

Comment: IOS <-> Android support is not necessary.... Anyways because I couldn't find any good service, I chose to go with my own server...

Answer (score 3):

Multiplayer SDK? you don't need an SDK.

Multiplayer works over network, all you need to run a multiplayer game is a discovery service to allow players to start playing together.

- This can be setup on a LAN using a [zeroconf protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking)
- Over the web by using a small web service.

Once the players are interconnected you start sending your data across nodes.

Comment: thanks, you are right.. For now I selected to use EC2+python_Tornado+Websocket.

Comment: node.js is becoming popular for multiplayer related services.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could look into open feint's competitors such as scoreloop, AGON, plus+, etc. Theres many different options available online, some doing more than others. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you want so I or someone else could make a suggestion.